# How do I alter a boolean value and display a string in views output?

Tags: views, hooks

Whats the best way to override a simple 0/1 boolean field in views output so instead of 0/1 it would output "Hello" or "Goodbye"?

EDIT: To improve on my question:

Whats the best way to add further options to the default view boolean handler? For example ...

```
$default_formats = array(
  'yes-no' => array(t('Yes'), t('No')),
  'true-false' => array(t('True'), t('False')),
  'on-off' => array(t('On'), t('Off')),
  'enabled-disabled' => array(t('Enabled'), t('Disabled')),
  'boolean' => array(1, 0),
  'unicode-yes-no' => array('✔', '✖'),
  'drunk-sober' => array(t('Drunk'), t('Sober')),
  'hello-goodbye' => array(t('Hello'), t('Goodbye')),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, that was a lot easier than I thought. Basically took a gander into node.views.inc and got the answer.

```
function MYMODULE_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['MYENTITY']['MYFIELD'] = array(
    'title' => t('MYFIELD'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_boolean',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
      'output formats' => array(
        'drunk-sober' => array(t('Drunk'), t('Sober')),
      ),
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_boolean_operator',
      'label' => t('MYFIELD'),
      'type' => 'yes-no',
      'use equal' => TRUE,
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Option that I used was to rewrite the output of the field and apply the answer as a class. Then I was able to style the class with either class name. I wanted to show a different icon depending on true/false, so set the bg accordingly

```
<div class="youclass-[replacement_flag]"></div>
```